# Fixed form to scrollable when reach at specified section on scrolling

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

need help!!!
I am using bootstrap5 in website and there is a registration form in banner section within row>col-md-5
Position of the form is fixed. I want to make form scrollable when reach at specific section otherwise it will remain fixed.

see he example in given link I need exactly like that.
https://dribbble.com/shots/3645773-Mixpanel-Scrolling-Form-Landing-Page

How can I do like that. Keep in mind I am using bootstrap 5 version

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery add jquery cdn on the bottom of your page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function() {
    var header = $(".yourform");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500)/*add class when reaching 500 change this*/ {
            header.removeClass('.anewclasswithfixedpositionaddedonyourform').addClass("anewclasswithabsolutepositionaddedonyourform");
        } else {
            header.removeClass(".anewclasswithabsolutepositionaddedonyourform").addClass('anewclasswithabsolutepositionaddedonyourform');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this method but in this method form goes up to its parent in banner section while I need the form don't go it its parent but scroll with the page to end of the page!!!  See the example

Comment: Have you tried .preventDefault ?

Comment: https://www.kevinpowell.co/article/positition-fixed-vs-sticky/ i found this one. you might not need javascript